# error App Engine Java Standard Environment JRE8 requires Java 1.8

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I develop on mac a project in google app engine with eclipse version 12.2018 and i get error like this when i compile the project: 
"App Engine Java Standard Environment JRE8 requires Java 1.8"

I added JRE system library java se 1.8

the project will compile without error

Answer (score 4):

You can check if java 1.8 is listening by going to (in eclipse):

**Preferences > Java > Installed JREs**

I would also recommend you to verify the file in order to know the version used:

**/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml**